# Is "because" a preposition & "for" a subordinator?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, subordinators

CGEL included a wide variety in the category of preposition (but not "BECAUSE").  But  some people say that **'for'** can be a subordinating conjunction (*subordinator*) as *'meaningless marker* of subordination' while **'because'** is a *preposition* with a *distinct meaning*, which can take a subordinate clause as prepositional complement.

**"I bought the book because I wanted to read it."**

Here, *'because'* is a preposition introducing a subordinate clause *"because I wanted to read it."*  (I doubt it)

We can write this sentence using the subordinator 'for'  :

*"I bought the book for reading it"*. ("reading it" : gerund-participle non-finite clause).

Is 'because' a preposition or a subordinator? Can we write the sentence with the subordinator **'for**' introducing **a finite subordinate clause**?

(Edit : *"Reason clauses are most commonly introduced by the subordinators 'because' and 'since'. . . . "* (CGEL, Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech Svartvik, Page : 1104.)

Comment: Yes, "because" is best classified as a preposition (though trad grammar treats it as a subordinating conjunction).

Comment: @BillJ, CGEL (page 1104) by Quirk, Greenbaum, says : "Reason clauses are most commonly introduced by the subordinators 'because' and 'since'. Is there any authentic reference that says that 'because' is a preposition?

Comment: CGEL tells about the wide varieties in the category of preposition; but I have found nowhere that because is a preposition. You only gave me a reference from wikitionary and said that because is a preposition. But I haven't found it in any grammar book.

Comment: I don't think think CGEL is wrong. The new idea (because is a preposition) is not backed by any authentic reference. It only exists in the very informal conversational structure : because + noun, such as "No work tomorrow because holidays!", which I think is ungrammatical.

Comment: Eh? Who's talking about the ungrammatical *"because holidays"? That has nothing to do with whether or not "because" is a prep. What research have you done on this? I suggest you read this and then come back to us [link](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494)

Comment: @BillJ, your link is excellent. It says very logically why 'because' isn't a conjunction either like 'that' or like 'and'. It proves that 'because of' isn't a preposition;  'because' and 'of' are two separate words. "Because" is a preposition which may take, as its complement, either a clause or a PP with 'of' as its head. But I haven't found this tremendous thought in any books that I have ever read. Btw, my questioning has helped me to get this link from you.

Comment: In this context, I also think that like 'because', though, when, if, unless, than, as, so -- all these are prepositions too !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which CGEL? "The **Cambridge**  Grammar of the English Language” (Quirk et al) -  or "**The Comprehensive** Grammar of the English Language” (Huddleston et al) – (I suspect Huddleston - I don't think anyone else would call "because" a preposition.)

Consider the nuances:
1. I bought the book because I wanted to read it. -> caused by my wanting to read it

2. I bought the book for I wanted to read it. -> for [the reason of] my wanting to read it.
3. I bought the book as I wanted to read it. -> [in the manner/circumstances of] my wanting to read it.
4. I bought the book when I wanted to read it. -> [at the time of] my wanting to read it.
5. I bought the book in Paris where I wanted to read it. -> [at the place of] my wanting to read it.

Etc.

You will see that “because” encompasses all types of “causes”, e.g. reason; purpose; manner; environment; time, etc. but “for” tends to be more specific

On usage, “The New Fowler's Modern English Usage” (Revised third edition 1998) explains

> **for**.
>
> 1 **For** is sometimes used as a coordinating conjunction, i.e. one that connects two independent sentences (see 3 below), but it should be said first that its most frequent use (apart from its employment as a preposition) is to join a sentence and a non-finite clause, esp. one of the type 'sentence +for + noun (phrase) + to-infinitive': *he waited for the lock to click; it is time for their legal rights to be clarified.* In such constructions the negative particle is normally placed before the to of the infinitive: *it would be more sensible for the code not to be enacted as law.*
>
> 2 Unlike some other coordinating conjunctions its position in the sentence is sequentially fixed (though even a century ago it was not), i.e. it cannot normally be placed at the beginning of a sentence. Its function is to introduce the ground or reason for something previously stated: *he picked his way down carefully, step by step, for the steps were narrow—*G. Greene, 1988 (*for the steps were narrow* could not have been placed before *he picked his way down, etc.*). In this respect it differs markedly from other coordinating conjunctions, e.g. because, since, which suffer from no such restriction.